# how to export React component from a typescript file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a class that looks like this:

> class ProductChecker extends React.Component { .... }

at the bottom of the file, I have:

> export default graphql(getSymbolInfoQuery)(ProductChecker);

where graphql is imported from react-apollo and getSymbolInfoQuery is a gql templated string.  When compiling the project, I am getting:

> src/client/gui/containers/product-checker.ts(3,10): error TS2305:
>   Module '"../components/product-checker"' has no exported member
>   'ProductChecker'

but when I comment out the bottom of the file line and do:

> export class ProductChecker extends React.Component {

that seems to be building just fine.  So it looks like the export at the bottom of the file does not "see" class/component declaration higher up, and says that its not found.
Any idea how to export a React class from a typescript source file?  THank you

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely your `import` statement where you are using this. I suspect you have:

```
import {ProductChecker} from "yourfilename";
```

but it should be:

```
import ProductChecker from "yourfilename";
```

The first assumes a named export, the second is for a default export.